# How to I install plugins and CMYK on gimp 2.10.10 snap package?

Tags: snap, gimp

Where do I dowload plugins for Gimp 2.10.10 like the resinthesizer plugin? I'm using the snap version and I have 3 folders on /home/snap/gimp 113, 130 and 165 where do I extract the plugins files? And how do I use CMYK color profile?

Comment: GIMP does not support CMYK as of now.

Answer (score 2):

The GIMP's preferences (GIMP → Preferences → Folders → Plugins) shows the following plugins directory for Snap installation:

```
/home/$USER/snap/gimp/165/.config/GIMP/2.10/plug-ins
```

You have to download and extract the plugin to this directory and then restart GIMP.